# Heroku error: page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'angular-route.js'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I've deployed my `nodejs` app to `heroku`. 
I have this file below as my `index.html` but somehow `heroku` is throwing me this error message to the chrome developer console (F12).

Error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://small-talkz.herokuapp.com/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $http.get('https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js').success(successCallback);
</script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9">
</script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<div ng-app="mymodule" ng-view>
</div>     
</html>
```

Comment: two things to solve this load if via `http` or change every `http` request with an `https`, heroku will invoke your all `http` request if you render your application via `https` ( like h2oo said  just use `//ajax.googleapis.com` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice your CDN that's hosting `angular-route` does not have HTTPS in it - means it is not served in secure protocol.

Either host a copy of it on Heroku (naturally - HTTPS) or find a new CDN to work with.

Edit: as mentioned you can just replace `http://` with `https://` since Google's APIs can be served through https.

Comment: Google APIs can be fully served with HTTPS.