# Faye not working while using https rails app and http faye app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, https, faye

I am having rails app and deployed in AWS EC2 with apache and unicorn. In this application I have used faye for messaging module.It is working fine with http application but Faye is not working while using https(ssl) for web application and http for Faye app.

In this situation are we really required https for both apps(web app and faye app)?
Please let me know.
Error:
The page at https://xxxx.xxxx was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://xxxxxx:9292/faye.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should serve your assets, faye.js in this case, through HTTPS. Take a look at this answer - [Heroku error: page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'angular-route.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354473/heroku-error-page-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-script-angu/38354599#38354599)